Factorizing groups into a product of solvable subgroups
Does every finite group $G$ have a factorization $G=H_1\cdots H_k$ where the $H_i$ for $1\le i\le k$ are solvable subgroups of $G$ and $|G|=|H_1|\cdots |H_k|$ (equivalently, every element of $G$ is uniquely expressible as a product $h_1\cdots h_k$ with $h_i\in H_i$)?
This would positively answer Existence of a special ordering of the elements of a finite group (II) (provided you accept the reasoning in my partial answer to that question). A solvable factorization for all simple $G$ would suffice.
Some related but distinct questions have been asked here. A version where the $H_i$ are only required to be subsets of $G,$ but we impose $|H_i|$ prime or equal to 4 seems to be a well known problem, see for example the comments to Is each finite group multifactorizable?.
If the $H_i$ are required to be Sylow subgroups of $G$ then such a factorization is not possible for $G=A_6,$ which has no Sylow $2,3,5$ subgroups $P,Q,R$ such that $A_6=PQR$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/850896). On the other hand, $A_6$ does have a solvable factorization $HLM$ where $H=C_{A_6}((12)(34)(56)),$ a group of order $24,$ $L=\langle (345)\rangle $ and $M=\langle (23456)\rangle.$ I can't see an obvious reason why all $A_n$ should have a solvable factorization. [But they do, see the proof in Dave Benson's comment.] $S_n$ also does, using $S_n=S_{n-1}\langle (12\dots n)\rangle$ and induction.

For $A_n$ with $n$ odd, there's an obvious factorisation $A_n=H_1A_{n-1}$ with $H_1$ generated by $(1,2,\dots,n)$. If $n=2m$ is even, let $H_1$ be generated by $(1,m+1)(m,2m)$ and $H_2$ be generated by $(1,2,..,m)(m+1,m+2,..,2m)$. Then $A_n=H_1H_2A_{n-1}$ where $A_{n-1}$ is the stabiliser of $n$.

Thanks @DaveBenson, that's very nice!

This looks hard to me. I think Liebeck, Praeger and Saxl have determined which finite simple groups $G$ have a factorization $G = AB$ for proper subgroups $A$ and $B.$ "Most" simple groups have no such factorization, so that makes an inductive argument to  answer the question positively look tricky.

By induction it is equivalent to ask whether every finite nonsolvable group has an exact factorization (i.e., factorization with unique representation) into some number of proper subgroups. Actually this also holds for solvable groups apart from some $p$-groups, by considering Hall subgroups, so one can replace "nonsolvable" by "not a $p$-group". This seems to be unknown for some of the largest sporadic simple groups.

This is not a definitive answer, but @SeanEberhard's comment reminded me about a Lemma of John Thompson's which relates to "triple factorizations" which arise in what are sometimes called pushing-up problems, especially in the study of finite simple groups of characteristic 2 type.
Thompson's lemma, which I think D. Gorenstein called Thompson's "three against two" argument is stated as as follows : If $A,B,C$ are subgroups of a group $G$, and $AB,AC$ and $BC$ are all subgroups of $G$, then $ABC$ is a subgroup of $G$ ( I don't think finiteness is required).
I think this can be proved as follows, though I don't think that this is the proof given in D. Gorenstein's single author book which gives a description of the Classification of finite simple groups: notice that we have $AB = BA, AC = CA$ and $BC = CB.$
Notice also that $ABC = (AB)C = A(BC),$ and similarly with any relabelling.
Now $ABC = A(BC) =(AB)C = (BA)C = B(AC) = B(CA) = (BC)A.$ Since $A$ and $BC$ are permutable subgroups of $G$, it follows that
$ABC = A(BC) = (BC)A$ is a subgroup of $G.$
Now I am not well acquainted with the literature on permutable groups, but it seems to me that this argument generalizes (by induction on $n$) as follows, and I would expect it to be in the literature somewhere: if $G$ is a group and $A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots ,A_{n}$ are pairwise permutable subgroups of $G$, then $A_{1}$ and $A_{2} \ldots A_{n}$ are permutable subgroups of $G$ and hence $A_{1}A_{2} \ldots A_{n}$ is a group.
We may suppose that $n > 2,$ or there is nothing to prove.
Thompson's result is the case $n = 3,$ so suppose that $n > 3$ and that the result has been established for both $n-2$  and $n-1$.
Then for $i\in \{1,2 \},$ we know $A_{3}\ldots A_{n}$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is permutable with both $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}.$ Then for $i \in \{1,2\}$, we see that  $A_{i}(A_{3} \ldots A_{n})$ is a subgroup of $G$ because $A_{i}$ and $A_{3}\ldots A_{n}$ are permutable subgroups of $G$.
Now by Thompson's Lemma, and its proof, since $A_{1},A_{2}$ and $A_{3} \ldots A_{n}$ are three pairwise permutable subgroups of $G$, we know that
$A_{1}A_{2}(A_{3} \ldots A_{n})$ is a subgroup of $G$, and that any one of these three subgroups is permutable with the product of the other two. Hence, in particular, $A_{2}A_{3} \ldots A_{n}$ is a subgroup of $G$ which is permutable with $A_{1}.$
In particular, if a finite group $G$ has $n \geq 3$ pairwise permutable subgroup $A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots ,A_{n}$ such that $|G| = \prod_{i=1}^{n}|A_{i}|,$ then we have $G = A_{1} \ldots A_{n}.$ Furthermore $G$ is the exact product of the two proper subgroups $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}A_{3} \ldots A_{n},$ as well as the exact product of three proper subgroups $A_{1},A_{2}$ and $A_{3} \ldots A_{n}.$
Unfortunately there are finite groups $G$ (other than $p$-groups) which do not have an exact factorization as a product of either two subgroups, or of three pairwise permutable subgroups, so this approach will not answer the question positively in general.
For example, if $X$ is the alternating group of degree $6$, then $X$ is not the exact product of two proper subgroups $A$ and $B.$  Hence $X$ has no expression as an exact product of three pairwise permutable subgroups either.
However, on the (slightly) positive side, if the finite group $G$ has $n$ mutually permutable subgroups $A_{1},A_{2}, \ldots ,A_{n}$ such that the product of their orders is $|G|$ and such that each $A_{i}$ is an exact product of some of its solvable subgroups, then $G$ is an exact product of some of its solvable subgroups.
